# Safari and background-clip: text not working well on multiple lines of display:inline text element

Tags: html, css, safari

I don't know why, but when I set

`background-clip: text`

to clip a gradient/image/whatever with text (display: inline), only Safari doesn't work as it is supposed to.

I recreated a pen with this issue: https://codepen.io/steexd/details/qBZVbWY

Test it with Firefox or Chrome and then with Safari: you will notice that multi-line text won't clip correctly the background gradient.

Expected result:

[image: Firefox]

Safari:

[image: Safari]

Any help would be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 9):

You can add `-webkit-box-decoration-break: clone;`

It will make the text legible, however it isn't exactly what you're asking for as it will repeat the gradient on each line.

[box-decoration-break property on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-decoration-break)

```css
h1 {
  max-width:120px;
}
span {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, red, pink);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-box-decoration-break: clone; 
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>Hi, i'm a text with a <span>long span gradient</span>.</h1>
</div>
```